# display ul li side by side

Tags: css, menu, html-lists

I'm trying to display a drop down part of a menu side by side instead of top to bottom. I have to display: none to make the menu work, and float: left isn't doing it. I'm out of ideas and not sure what else to do needing the display: none to be there to hide the list until it needs to show. I've thrown float: left pretty much everywhere.
The CSS:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    min-width: 200px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
} 
ul#navigation {
    float: left;
} 
ul#navigation li {
    float: left;
    border: 1px black solid;
    min-width: 200px;
} 
ul.sub_navigation {
    position:absolute;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    display: none;
} 
ul.sub_navigation li {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
} 
a,a:active,a:visited {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('home.php', 'body');">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('projects.php', 'body');">Projects</a>
            <ul class="sub_navigation" style="float: left;">
                    <!-- pull projects with P H P -->
                    <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('openproj.php?id=<? echo $row['id']; ?>', 'body');"><? echo $row['name']; ?></a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('createproj.php', 'body');">Add a project</a></li>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('pubfiles.php', 'body');">Public Files</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('users.php', 'body');">Users</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('settings.php', 'body');">Settings</a></li>
            <!-- only pull if admin and logged in per P H P session-->
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage('admin.php', 'body');">Admin</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have not done so already, I suggest reading this: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns/

Comment: Also, this would be helpfull: http://phrogz.net/JS/ul2menu/purecss_testsuite.html

Comment: I guess I'm missing it in both those articles, but I still don't see what more I can add besides the inline and lefts that I already have in there.

Comment: What is the relevance of the PHP source code? The actual markup would make more sense. And please, for the life of Brian, make a http://jsfiddle.net demo.

Comment: What is your real problem here? The menu is horizontal, but it falls down because its not fitting the width: http://jsfiddle.net/t4zgN/. To show the submenus, you will have to use javascript.

Comment: PHP is just for pulling the info into the drop down from my db.
I was hoping there was a way in css to do it instead of javascript, but alas javascript it is. Thanks guys, and sorry about the code. Last I was posting for help jsfiddle was either not around or not too famous. I'll use it from now on.

Comment: I don't even know for sure what you're describing. That's why you should make a fiddle with actual client-side markup. The PHP source is meaningless to the question.

Comment: You only need to use one `float: left;` in your `#navigation li.dropdown`, too much of it and all will go wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seemed that putting `width=auto;` in both the `ul li` and its child, as well as changing the child positioning to `relative`, made it work the way I needed it to.

I appreciate everyone's input as it brought me to being one step closer to being done with this and learning a lot more about this site, and css with jquery.

Link: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvNTb/2/)

Answer (score 3):

You Can implement your HTML and CSS code this way, then It will work properly.

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   width:400px;
   float:left;
 }

.menu ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style:none;
  border:0;
  float:left;
}

.menu ul li {
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
}

.menu ul li a {
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:13px 10px;
  text-decoration:none;
  border:1px
  solid #000;
}
```